# Existing table in SQL Server causing 'There is already an object named '***' in the database' error

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a table in python using azure sql server, when i run this line of code below i get the following error:

> 'There is already an object named '***' in the database'.

```
def del_final_trades(new_table_name, cl_table_name, cp_table_name):
cursor.execute('''SELECT * INTO {newt} FROM {cl_t} INNER JOIN {cp_t} ON
    {cl_t}.[CL_Trade ID] = {cp_t}.[CP_Trade ID]'''.format(newt=new_table_name, cl_t=cl_table_name,
                                                          cp_t=cp_table_name))
```

The error is correct, the table does exist but how do I drop the table if its `NOT NULL` and create a new one?

I understand the logic, I'm just struggling to put it into a working code, any help is appreciated!

Comment: When you Google'd "SQL Server drop table if not null" what did you find?

Comment: I understand you would write the following in SQL: `IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Table', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Table;` but how does this differ in python?

Comment: Why would Python be different?

Answer (score 1):

You need to test if the table exists within a drop command:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [Table name]
```